# Is there a list of all possible permissions an app can have?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there somewhere a complete overview of all permissions for an android application?
I've been searching for a while now. There are a lot of specific examples, but no complete list.

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Comment: There are an uncountable number of possible permissions, as devices and apps can define new ones. [The `Manifest.permission` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) covers the ones that are part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: i guess, to technically answer your question then, the answer would be "no", because you can always create your own :) it's only in reference to the actual sdk that you _could_ get a complete list